# notMNIST not downloadable in TensorFlow Udacity course

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm doing the Udacity TensorFlow course, first exercise: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/1_notmnist.ipynb

OSX 10.11 (El Capitan)
Python 2.7
virtualenv installation of TF

I am getting an error:

"Exception: Failed to verifynotMNIST_large.tar.gz. Can you get to it with a browser?"

It finds the “small” file, but not the “large.”  Appreciate help.  Thanks.

Here is the whole block of code:

```
>>> url = 'http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/notMNIST/'
>>> 
>>> def maybe_download(filename, expected_bytes):
...   """Download a file if not present, and make sure it's the right size."""
...   if not os.path.exists(filename):
...     filename, _ = urlretrieve(url + filename, filename)
...   statinfo = os.stat(filename)
...   if statinfo.st_size == expected_bytes:
...     print('Found and verified', filename)
...   else:
...     raise Exception(
...       'Failed to verify' + filename + '. Can you get to it with a browser?')
...   return filename
...
```

Here is what gets returned:

```
 >>> train_filename = maybe_download('notMNIST_large.tar.gz', 247336696)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in maybe_download
Exception: Failed to verifynotMNIST_large.tar.gz. Can you get to it with a browser?
>>> test_filename = maybe_download('notMNIST_small.tar.gz', 8458043)
Found and verified notMNIST_small.tar.gz
```

Comment: You code is specifically testing the size of the download and comparing it to a pre-determined filesize. If the size does not match, then it raises the exception. Check the size of the downloaded file (manually) and re-verify the size you expect.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, I was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Also face the same situation.

That is a simple thing to handle it and continue.

> There's a size mismatch.
>
> Just re-run the code with **force=True**, and
> it works right now!

If you try to download it manually it will also be Ok.

As described in this thread: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1475

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (workaround?) of the issue in Udacity forum.

https://discussions.udacity.com/t/not-able-to-load-the-dataset-for-assingment-1/160124

In the page, two solutions are proposed.

a. Download notMNIST_large.tar.gz locally via browser, and copy it using docker command.

or

b. Add "User-Agent" header in fetching script.

I think both approaches works fine.

Comment: @h7r How do I copy it using docker command? I just try copy-paste and it doesn't work.